# How can I update the photo each second in my django template?

Tags: django, django-templates

everyone. I am pretty new with django.
There is a particular position to show the photo in my django template, and the photo should be updated each second. How can I do that? (Paths for new photos come from the database. I know how to get them from db.)
I only know how to return a html with a url request, but how can I update a particular item in that html without a new url request?

More info.: The photos have to be shown are generated in real time by another process, so do the paths for the photos.

Actually, I do not implement it yet. I am still learning django, but I can simulate the situation by simple codes as follows:

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [ url(r'^hello/$', hello_world),]
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from datetime import datetime

def hello_world(request):
    return render(request, 'hello_world.html', {
        'current_time': str(datetime.now()),
    })
```

hello_world.html:

```
<!-- hello_world.html -->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>I come from template!!</title>
        <style>
            body {
               background-color: lightyellow;
            }
            em {
                color: LightSeaGreen;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
<script>
    setInterval(function() {
        fetch("{% url 'hello_ajax' %}").then(function (response) {
    var current_time = response.json().current_time;
    console.log(current_time);
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = current_time;
        });
    }, 1000);
</script>
        <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    <em id="test"></em>
    </body>
</html>
```

We can update the current_time by refresh the page, but how about update the current_time each second without refresh the page?  We can see the photo as the current_time to simulate my case.

**Update:**
It finally works:

```
<script>
    setInterval(function() {
        fetch("{% url 'hello_ajax' %}").then(response => response.json())
.then(data => {
    // you can access your data here
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = data.current_time;
});
    }, 1000);
</script>
```

I am wondering why it is not working with:

```
<script>
        setInterval(function() {
            fetch("{% url 'hello_ajax' %}").then(response =>{
        // you can access your data here
        document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = response.json().current_time;
    });
        }, 1000);
</script>
```

it says that "(index):22 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to execute 'json' on 'Response': body stream is locked at fetch.then.data"
Any idea?

Comment: Well if you want to update a photo each second you can use `django background tasks` and define a function (which is called tasks) in it which will run as a corn process in background every second. And in that function you can define your logic. Here is my answer how to use it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54225303/signal-django-to-run-a-task/54225921#54225921

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can achieve it only with some JavaScript, and thing like [setTimeout](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp). If it won't be a big list, you could render it to the JavaScript array and then use e.g. `setTimeout` to switch the photo. **It's not the best idea** (I even remember reading some article with some valid points why it is a bad, will try to find it), but would do the work.
So, you could do something like this, at the end of body in the template:

```
<script>
    arrayOfUrls = [
        {% for url in urls}"{{ url }}",{% endfor %}
    ];
    function switchPhoto(urlArray, switchTo) {
        // if to go back to 0 if array finished
        document.getElementById("your-photo-id").src = urlArray[switchTo];
        setTimeout(switchPhoto, 1000, urlArray, switchTo + 1);
    }
    switchPhoto(arrayOfUrls, 0);
</script>
```

After update:
if you don't want to refresh the page, the solution would be probably the following:

`views.py`

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
def hello_world(request):
    return render(request, 'hello_world.html', {
        'current_time': str(datetime.now()),
    })

def hellow_world_ajax(request):
    return JsonResponse({'current_time': str(datetime.now())})
```

Add `url(r'^hello_ajax/$', hellow_world_ajax, name="hello_ajax"),` to `urls.py`.

And in the body of the template write JavaScript using e.g.: [setInterval](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) and either vanilla JS [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) or some js library / framework insert the periodic update logic:

```
<script>
    setInterval(function() {
        fetch("{% url 'hello_ajax' %}").then(function (response) {
            document.getElementById("your-photo-id").src = response.json().current_time;
        });
    }, 1000);
</script>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the reply. Image paths in the database are generated in real time, so the length of the list for image paths will be infinite typically.

Comment: In this case you'll have either to limit the length passed to the template, or switch to e.g. AJAX calls to your app, to retrieve new images. Could you post some of your code? The view at least.

Comment: Update the answer, I hope it'll help.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I got the msg each sec. in cmd windows as follows:
`[17/Jan/2019 09:25:13] "GET /hello_ajax/ HTTP/1.1" 200 46`

The time in page is still not upadte if I do not refresh the page.
I found some midunderstanding in the js "document.getElementById("your-photo-id").src = response.json().current_time;"
The hello_world.html, it only updates and shows the current_time, not any photo. I want to know how to update variables in .html by this simple case, so I can do the photo replacement case on my own.

Comment: I just update the hello_world.html, but it shows undefined on the webpage