# How are periodic tasks deleted from Celery?

Tags: python, django, celery

In Celery and Django, whenever I delete the code for a periodic task from its tasks.py file it is not removed from the django_celery_beat_periodictask table in Postgres and thus is still called.

I have attempted the following:

- Stopping Django, Celery and Beat.
- Restarting  Django, Celery and Beat.
- Killing all workers via "kill".
- Using app.autodiscover_tasks().
- Creating new periodic tasks in new tasks.py files in different modules works as expected but deleting them does not.

Deleting the tasks via Django's admin page works but this is not ideal. I want the task discovery process to handle it.

Is there a way for the tasks discovery process to handle deleted periodic tasks?

Comment: No there is not.

Comment: try `celery -A proj_name purge`

Comment: If you can I would suggest you to try `django-background-tasks` instead of `celery` take a look at my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54225303/signal-django-to-run-a-task/54225921#54225921